# Django-registration partially included in django, getting name error

Tags: python, django, installation, django-registration, nameerror

I have installed django-registration with pip, version 0.7.

Then with

**urls.py**

```
from core.forms import UserRegistrationForm

from registration.views import register

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','form_class': RegistrationForm}, name='registration_register'),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),

)
```

**core/forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
```

I'm getting (**updated**)

```
ImportError at /accounts/register/

No module named forms
```

Now, if with a shell i do:

```
>>> import registration.forms

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/registration/forms.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    if not settings.DATABASES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

i get this error.

But `import registration` goes well, and i use in `urls.py registration.views.register` without problems.

What can i do to debug this problem?

**UPDATE**: thanks to @DrTyrsa i tried with python manage.py shell

and import registration.forms works, but doesn't work in my file

```
>>> import registration.forms
>>> import core.forms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/www/vhosts/opineo/core/forms.py", line 2, in <module>
    from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
ImportError: No module named forms
```

i don't understand why.. registration is installed with pip and it's in the python path

Comment: Try your import in `manage.py shell`

Comment: `NameError at /accounts/register/` – that's NameError, not ImportError. Can you paste the whole view code?

Comment: sorry that was a clipboard typo, an old error :( the error is always ImportError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is "im an idiot" :)

while i was checking everything i noticed that i had a folder called registration with an **init**.py inside.

That was overwriting django-registration include; renamed it and the error is gone.